# Stupor automobile-correct

Tags: story, english, language, humor

I recentle bought a new phon. I cet the local tew Auctralee, and auph I went. It wauc good tew hav a new phon. I wauc then praumpted and wethe I wanted predictiv tecct, and the trabl ctated.

Every time I start a parargraph, it's all phine, but thene mei phone starts thineking it's beter thane mey. It gets to ther poinet where allmeost every whord is geting kerrekterd.

Which brings me to my other problerms - ther derlet botern dosn't erpeer on ther keboard, it whon't let me edit ene whork that Y've don, kope and past don't whork, and fynerly, to kap it oarl of, Y kan't torn it of!

I trid to report it to the manuotuorers, but they 'need to now ecsactlee whut's gowwhing on sow whee [they] can fics it eficientlee'. Can uo plees tel mee whut's rong sow I can get it ficsd as son as posibl? Thancs! It's poting mi sowciel lif into ciambls, as I can't comuoniceyt whith eneeuun properlee for mor than haf ey sentens.

Comment: This is nice! :) +1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the wheule anse, but it eppies that

> whenever you introduce a new phoneme, your phone just sticks with the first spelling of that phoneme until the end of the paragraph. I think this is done as per the Australian pronunciation, but I couldn't find an IPA translator for that, so I'll illustrate the point with UK English. For example, 'recently' is pronounced /ˈriːsntli/, but since the first /i/ corresponds to an E, so will the second one. 'To' is pronounced /tuː/, but /uː/ was already introduced as the EW in 'new' earlier, so it was replaced with that. 'Was' is /wɒz/, but /ɒ/ has already appeared in the AU of 'Australia' (/ɒˈstreɪliːə/). Etc.

Comment: Correct! (I was hoping it would last a little longer :P) I'll award the checkmark tomorrow however, so the question can get a little more attention. If I don't, ping me on this comment (I'm a little forgetful)

Comment: Thank you. I was a little curious about the 'kan't torn it of' part, but then I guess it was just for the sake of the story.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't turn it off because if I could the story would have been a bit flat.